# Navigation bar with large titles and right UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I am trying to replicate the behaviour shown in Podcasts app (by apple). 
[image]

As shown in the image, the `rightBarButtonItem` is aligned with the title "Listen Now". The icon even scrolls up with it (until it disappears).

The default behavior for a `rightBarButtonItem` with large titles it is shown in the library section:
[image]

Anyone knows how to replicate the first example? I need a button aligned with the title.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think they use actual large titles in the podcast app. It looks like they are just using a `tableHeaderView` and making it appear as though it's part of the navigation bar. This works because they erase the `shadowImage` of the navigation controllers the navigation bar. Then they place a label with a `.largeTitle` sized font in the table header view. For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    lazy var titleStackView: TitleStackView = {
        let titleStackView = TitleStackView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 44.0)))
        titleStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return titleStackView
    }()

    lazy var tableHeaderView: UIView = {
        let tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: 44.0)))
        tableHeaderView.addSubview(titleStackView)
        titleStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableHeaderView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
        titleStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableHeaderView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        titleStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableHeaderView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0).isActive = true
        titleStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableHeaderView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        return tableHeaderView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = nil
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "\(UITableViewCell.self)")
    }

}
```

Where `TitleStackView` is a custom view with the UI that you want to appear as the "large title" UI.

For example:

```
class TitleStackView: UIStackView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        axis = .horizontal
        alignment = .center
        addArrangedSubview(titleLabel)
        addArrangedSubview(button)
    }

    lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle).pointSize, weight: .heavy)
        label.text = "Listen Now"
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    lazy var button: UIButton = {
        let buttonWidth: CGFloat = 35.0
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: buttonWidth, height: buttonWidth)))
        button.backgroundColor = .purple
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("B", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonWidth).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonWidth).isActive = true
        button.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.height * 0.5
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return button
    }()
}
```

Finally, they use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` callback to monitor when to show the title:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let maxTitlePoint = tableView.convert(CGPoint(x: titleStackView.titleLabel.bounds.minX, y: titleStackView.titleLabel.bounds.maxY), from: titleStackView.titleLabel)
    title = scrollView.contentOffset.y > maxTitlePoint.y ? "Listen Now" : nil
 }
```

If you do all of those things you end up with an effect like the following:

[image: Screencast]

Comment: Thank you @beyouwulf ! I took a very similar approach when I did not find any solutions involving navigation bar.

Comment: Dont think this answer is working for me. Headerview is not part of the navigation bar and it causes some issues with coloring. And more importantly, if table view does not have enough content to scroll. You end up with having two showing at the same time.

Comment: Agree. I don't think this is what apple is exactly doing.. When u push/pop a view controller via this approach, it doesn't work/look great like it does with Podcasts app ...